# Razor. How to cut a message

Tags: css

I have a HTML file with 2 DIV elements on the same line.

```
<div>
     <div class="left"> @user.Message</div>
     <div class="right"> @user.Name</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
    width:80%;
    float: left;
 }
.right{
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
 }
```

If I set the message width in first DIV to a value larger than 80%, my structure is crashing.

Can I split the message  `@user.Message` to ensure that the message is less than 80%?

Comment: 1) do you really need 80% for user.Name?  2) you can use `overflow-x: hidden;` to hide the content so no scroll bar will show.  You will also have to add `display: block;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the width, overflow, white-space, and text-overflow properties to achieve a graceful trim of the content to make sure it doesn't destroy your structure:

```css
.wrapper{
    width:600px;
}
.left{
    width:80%;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
.right{
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="left">this should be a nice long string, over 80% of the total width of the parent, any more should be hidden from view gracefully</div>
     <div class="right">should be 20%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` for `.left` and `.right` and after that use width 80% for `.left` and 20% for `.right`:

```
.left{
display: inline-block;
width: 80%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

`text-overflow: ellipsis` will cut of the extra words by using `...`

Answer (score 0):

I would not use razor to achieve formatting goals. To answer your question though; you can create a [custom extension](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site). Following that link's instructions you can do something like this:

```cs
helper TrimmedContainer(string content) {
  <div class="left" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
      @content
  </div>
}

@MyHelpers.TrimmedContainer(@user.Message)
```

Again I would not do this. I would follow the approach of creating a class with the above styles and adding that class to the div.